# Rearrange Stacked Columns on Mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to rearrange a number of stacked columns on mobile devices using Bootstrap. I'm aware of the push/pull method when it comes to rearranging two columns next to each other but I'm running into difficulty when it comes to rearranging three.

In the example below I'd like the blue column to appear on top on the break point. The order should be blue-green-red on smaller screens, and remain the way it's on desktop devices.

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="green" class="col-sm-12">
    Green
  </div>

  <div id="blue" class="col-sm-4">
    Blue
  </div>

  <div id="red" class="col-sm-8">
    Red
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wqg0w4kn/

I've tried a number of push and pulls but can't seem to get it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, all the prefixes are necessary (for now):

```css
#blue {background-color: #3F77B3;}
#green {background-color: #95E289;}
#red {background-color: #FF7878;}
.row.reordered {color: rgba(255,255,255,.21);}
.row.reordered > * {padding: 3rem; font-size: 2rem; font-family: cursive;}

/* you only need the code below. above is just styling */

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .row.reordered {
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #red {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
  }
  #blue {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -webkit-order: 1;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    order: 1;
  }
  #green {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row reordered">
  <div id="green" class="col-sm-12">
    Green
  </div>

  <div id="blue" class="col-sm-4">
    Blue
  </div>

  <div id="red" class="col-sm-8">
    Red
  </div>
</div>
```

Just swap the color names as you need them. :)

Comment: Well then. I no longer feel bad for not being able to figure that one out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite possible with bootstrap's classes, since you're changing the order of elements.

You'll have to use the flexbox-layout, see
https://jsfiddle.net/sfqzsus2/

You can change the order of the elements with `order: n`

Comment: Bootstrap and `flexbox` are not incompatible. One just needs to understand what particular CSS properties each of them influence and/or are influenced by. Flexbox is already (optionally) part of Bootstrap 4.